# Limit what javascript a user can input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I want to allow users to enter their own math formulas into a field that I can run via javascript, but I only want them to enter math related code and also let them have access to only the Math object.

So I only want the user to be able to enter math symbols (+, -, *, %, etc) and use any function in the Math object.

I initially thought about using regex on the client and server to verify that they are only typing in what i allowed, and since they wont be able to run that code before it goes to the server, i thought maybe it would be OK, but I still don't know if just regex itself would even work for this.

How can I go about safely allowing and trusting a users input like this?

Edit: The formulas will always run on the client, but I will store them in the db as a string that i can send to them when they want to run it.

Comment: There's only one place to securely validate user input, on the server.

Comment: Well, if the app is on the client and the server is just serving the app, then i  don't see why can't he validate on the client.

Comment: You're going to want to use a DSL and parser to allow users to use math functions. Regular expressions are likely to be involved but building a DSL from scratch would be too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Yep I know and thats why i wont let the code run before it goes to the server, but what I'm not sure of is how to strip everything but Math object and symbols

Comment: If you're planning to run user-submitted code on your server, that's a serious and complicated security concern. (JavaScript is taking baby steps in the direction of making this all more practical, but it's got a *very* long way to go.) Arbitrary JavaScript code can be run through a series of special characters like `[]()~!^` with almost no letters at all -- creating a secure validation method is much more complicated than it might sound. As others have suggested, you'd be much better off creating a simple parser and evaluating the expressions yourself, rather than evaluating them as JS.

Comment: If you are doing Math operations on the server be very careful, specially on single-thread server instances. Some operations can take forever and they will block your server instance.

Comment: @MinusFour the formulas they enter will only be run on the client side, i just will store them as a string in the database and serve it back to them when they want to run it

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks for the comment. That helped lead me to find MathJs which does everything I need and then some.

Answer (score 1):

So a number of comments led me to find [MathJs](http://mathjs.org/), and from reading some of the docs and comments on that site I see it is safe to allow user input and also allows the Math object.

And combining this with [workerpool](https://github.com/josdejong/workerpool) to limit execution time, I think that should have everything I'm needing.

Thanks to those who helped point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that text will not be executed on the server then conceptually you can try `evalFormula` below :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function evalFormula(str) {

      // shielding 
      var window = null;  
      var document = null;

      // shortcuts
      var abs = Math.abs;

      return eval(str); 
    }

    console.log( evalFormula("abs(-42)") );    
    console.log( evalFormula("document.write('')") ); // throws error

    </script>
  </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the function contains `// shielding` section that shall contain "caps" for all "dangerous" objects that shall be prohibited in formula context. 
Note: that set is quite difficult to define in full but in principle possible.

Local scope of the function may contain shortcuts of Math functions, so they can be used as `abs(-42)` but not as `Math.abs(-42)`.

Idea of the code above: In JS `eval()` gets executed in context of current function. So all its local variables are available for the text being evaluated.

Comment: Huh, thats pretty clever imo. Never thought to create new window and document vars. I do see how it could become pretty difficult to define everything you did and didnt want though. However, your answer did lead me to find MathJs and from initial reading on that site, it is safe to use that lib to eval a formula which includes Math object.

Comment: `[].constructor.constructor('return document')().write('oh no');`

Comment: @JeremyBanks I know and there are more of those. It can be dangerous if one can write function for the use of others. But if your app is just a "smart calculator" for personal use then such a shielding prevents *accidental* input of something like `location.href = "other.htm"`, not more.